# Flutter: getting null value even after setting the provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to fix this for days now, and I can't get around it, I have a provider called "Index provider" and when ever I try to set it to a value it looks like it has been set but when I try to call it. all of a sudden the value is null

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IndexProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  String _chatUid = "";
  String _receiverUid = "";
  String _receiverName = "";
  String _userUid = "";

  int get selectedIndex => this._selectedIndex;
  String get chatUid => this._chatUid;
  String get userUid => this._userUid;
  String get receiverUid => this._receiverUid;
  String get receiverName => this._receiverName;

  set setSelectedIndex(int value) {
    print(value);
    _selectedIndex = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set setChat(String value) {
    print(value);
    _chatUid = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set setUserUid(String userUid) {
    _userUid = userUid;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set setReceiverUid(String receiverUid) {
    _receiverUid = receiverUid;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set setReceiverName(String receiverUid) {
    _receiverUid = receiverUid;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

How I set it

```
IndexProvider indexProvider = Provider.of<IndexProvider>(context, listen: false);
    indexProvider.setUserUid = uid;
```

and how I call it

```
IndexProvider indexProvider = Provider.of<IndexProvider>(context, listen: true);
String userUid = indexProvider.userUid;
print(userUid);
```

and each time I try to print it I got this

```
The method 'allMatches' was called on null.
Receiver: null
```

thank you for you time <3

Comment: Post the code that has (object).allMatches.  That's where the null reference is coming from.  And, you should set the user ID like this:  indexProvider.setUserId(uid).

Answer (score 0):

Here you are assigning the provider to a variable and then changing that variable. You are not changing the provider value.

```
IndexProvider indexProvider = Provider.of<IndexProvider>(context, listen: false);
```

Use this instead,

```
Provider.of<IndexProvider>(context, listen: false).setUserUid = uid;
```